# How many instantiations of template there are?

Tags: c++, dllimport, template-specialization

I've created `Dynamic library` project `Foo` and it has following code in the `Foo.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#ifdef MYLIB_EXPORTS
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class MYLIB_API Foo
{
};

template class MYLIB_API std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo>;
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;
```

I use `Foo` class from my `ConsoleApplication1`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Foo.h"

template class std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo>; // (1)

int _tmain(int /*argc*/, _TCHAR* /*argv*/[])
{
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo()); // (2)
    return 0;
}
```

The code above is compiled without error/warnings. I use `Visual Studio 2008 (v90)` toolset to compile this. Both projects is compiled with `/W4`.

**Questions**:
1. Why (1) doesn't produce any compiler errors/warnings? I've expected here something like `C2011 type redefinition`. *I suspect (1) is ignored.*
2. How many instantiations of `std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo>` there are? As it is compiled, I've expected that there two instantiation: one in the `Foo` and another in the `consoleapplication1`.
3. Which instantiation (if there are many) is used at (2)?

---

<s>**UPDATE1:**

I compiled this with `Assembly With Source Code (/FAs)`, and seems that both [`Foo`](https://gist.github.com/evgeny-t/d36f206fe6710dc524f1) and [`ConsoleApplication1`](https://gist.github.com/evgeny-t/c1afdfcd9e46d57b4709) contain implementation of `shared_ptr<Foo>`. Doesn't this mean that there are two `shared_ptr<Foo>` explicit instantiation?</s>

Comment: [definition vs declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Comment: I'd be glad if someone clarify `update1`.

Comment: `update1` was kind of misconception

Comment: *"1. Why (1) doesn't produce any compiler errors/warnings?"* Well the compiler is at least not required to: [temp.spec]/5 "For a given template and a given set of *template-arguments*, an explicit instantiation definition shall appear at most once in a program [...] An implementation is not required to diagnose a violation of this rule."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) isn't a redefinition, it's a forward declaration.

(2) There only needs to be one. I don't know why you expect any more. I supposed it's possible that a given compiler might produce more than one, but why? and it would figure pretty high on their bug list if it did.

(3) See (2).

Comment: I've thought that line `template class std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo>;` does instantiation of `shared_ptr` with `Foo`. That's why I expected more than one

Comment: `template class std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo>;` is *not* a forward-declaration, but an explicit instantiation definition. A forward-declaration would look like this: `namespace std{namespace tr1{template<class T> class shared_ptr;}}`